# How to make soft body 2D in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have a task to make a game like that in the picture that I stuck. There are many examples on YouTube how to make jelly objects, but they are all for 3D, and I need it for 2D. I need to be able to control the adhesion of slimes or not sticking. Tell me how to do it. Perhaps with the help of assets or standard means of unity.  Thank.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wXTE.jpg

Comment: "Tell me how to start on this" is not a valid question format for StackOverflow. Your question should center on a reproducable error/unexpected behavior, preferably with an MCVE.

Comment: Rather ask for assistance on a specific aspect of your problem, instead of simply asking people to write the code for you.

Comment: I do not ask you to write code in my place. I meant: do I need to manually write code or are there ready-made assets

Comment: Help me please!